# react nested children with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this piece of code runs without any warnings. I would have assumed that it would say duplicate keys, but for some reason, event though i can see siblings with the same key, it doesn't throw an error. why is that?

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4];

export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {a.map((num, index) =>
        b.map((sec, secindex) => <Button key={secindex}>hi</Button>)
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

the children's keys are like so:

[image]

Comment: You're passing a 2D array to React, if you flattened that array then you would see the error. `a.flatMap((num, index) => ...` would yield an error of duplicate keys.

Comment: @pilchard but still, why is that? the children are technically siblings, what is the difference? (i understand that they are not the same but what exactly is different)